# Правильное написание выражения: «при чём тут цена?» или «причём тут цена?»

Tags: орфография, предлоги, союзы, слитно-раздельно, местоимения

«При чём тут цена?» или «причём тут цена?» Как правильно написать в данном выражении: слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Заглянем в правила (см. подробнее [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/)).

1. Когда пишем слитно.

> Союзы *притом* и *причём* пишутся **слитно**, их надо отличать от сочетаний предлога с местоимениями *при том* и *при чём*. Союзы *притом* и *причём*  имеют присоединительное значение, синонимичны и легко заменяют друг друга; имеют синонимы *да и*, *вместе с тем*, *к тому же*: *Мне вздумалось завернуть под навес, где стояли наши лошади, посмотреть, есть ли у них корм, и **притом** (причем, к тому же, вместе с тем) осторожность никогда не мешает* (Т.); *Он вернулся через два часа и получил тот же ответ, **причём** (притом, к тому же, вместе с тем) лакей как-то косо посмотрел на него* (Т.).

2. Когда пишем раздельно.

> Сочетание *при чём* употребляется в вопросительных предложениях или в сложноподчиненных предложениях при присоединении изъяснительных придаточных: **При чём** здесь наши отношения?; *Я спросил его, **при чём** здесь приезжие гости, если они никакого отношения к его работе не имеют.* Сочетание *при том* предполагается в ответе на вопрос, содержащий сочетание *при чём*: *Наши отношения **при том**, что я не смогу выступить с таким предложением* (ответ на вопрос: ***При чём** тут наши отношения?*).

**ВЫВОД**

Поскольку у нас именно *вопросительное предложение*, то "при чём" следует писать раздельно: **"при чём тут цена?"**.